Did the FAA used to require pilots to have valid sectional for VFR cross country flights?
Did there used to be an FAR in the 1990ies that required VFR pilots to have in their possession a valid sectional for cross country flights? I seem to remember this rule from before 2000, but can't find any such rule in the FARs today.
